# Position footer div at bottom inside table-cell with 100% width

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a container `div` with `display: table` and three inner divs that have `display: table-cell`.

The two outer table-cells have a fixed width, the inner table-cell has `width:100%`. So it scales with the size of the browser.

I also have a footer div that I'm trying to place at the bottom of the middle cell, with a `width: 100%`. But it expands way over the width of the middle table-cell.

How can this issue be fixed?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9opnx9r8/

HTML

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cell1,
.cell3 {
  min-width: 150px;
}

.cell2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:table; min-height: 100%;">
  <div class="cell cell1">
    <h1>C1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell2">
    <h1>C2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>List</li>
      <li>must</li>
      <li>stay</li>
      <li>top</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="text">FOOTER TEXT HERE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell3">
    <h1>C3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you want it to be in the middle container at the bottom or just at the bottom of the page but aligned in the middle

Comment: I think all you need to do is add `position:relative` to `.cell2`.

Comment: you just need to remove position: absolute for .text class to get it in the middle container at the bottom

Comment: Hard to tell what you want, is the table supposed to be 100% height? is the footer supposed to be contained inside of cell2 or outside of it? The issue right now is the footer is 100% width of the page because you have no other positioned element, so it is bigger than cell2. If you put cell2 relative then your footer overlaps with the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The containing block for absolutely positioned elements is the nearest positioned ancestor.

If there is no positioned ancestor, the containing block is the viewport.

Therefore, add `position: relative` to the element that should be the containing block for the footer.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cell1, .cell3 {
  min-width: 150px;
}

.cell2 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; /* NEW */
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: inherit;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:table; min-height: 100%;">
    <div class="cell cell1">
      <h1>C1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell2">
      <h1>C2</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>List</li>
        <li>must</li>
        <li>stay</li>
        <li>top</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="text">FOOTER TEXT HERE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell3">
      <h1>C3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this will create an overlap with OP's current setup https://jsfiddle.net/9opnx9r8/1/

Comment: @Huangism, that's a separate issue. The footer is now located where it is supposed to be. The question is not about sizing and alignment.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, the overlap is no issue. Thanks.

Comment: I can't help but feel a bit disappointed with that reply but you are not wrong

Comment: @Huangism, you shouldn't be disappointed. There were no details provided about the content of those boxes, so there was no point in trying to fix the overlap. The fix would be based on pure speculation and likely not be helpful to the OP.